# webdriver error "urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I'm new to python, when I want to run following simple code I got error:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.whatsmyip.org")
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\insta bot\instagram.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 177, in __init__
    executor = FirefoxRemoteConnection(
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\remote_connection.py", line 27, in __init__
    RemoteConnection.__init__(self, remote_server_addr, keep_alive, ignore_proxy=ignore_proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 155, in __init__
    self._conn = self._get_connection_manager()
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 143, in _get_connection_manager
    urllib3.ProxyManager(self._proxy_url, **pool_manager_init_args)
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 480, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using?

Comment: @AlexeyR. selenium V 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears when your client code (your test) attempts to send a command to a WebDriver service. Since it is REST (over http) Selenium takes the proxy that is defined in environment variable for corresponding protocol:

```py
def _get_proxy_url(self):
    if self._url.startswith('https://'):
        return os.environ.get('https_proxy', os.environ.get('HTTPS_PROXY'))
    elif self._url.startswith('http://'):
        return os.environ.get('http_proxy', os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY'))
```

Looks like the value that is assigned to one of (or both) those vars is not a proper URL.

The solution would be:

- either to fix the URL
- or to toggle `ignore_local_proxy_environment_variables` in `FirefoxOptions`

Comment: my problem solved by changing my code to:

`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.ignore_local_proxy_environment_variables()


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")`

Thanks @AlexeyR